# How to download a file via https using QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: python, qtnetwork

I'm trying to write a class using `QtNetwork` to download a file without freezing my GUI.
This seems to work with http URLs (tested with "http://webcode.me"), but not with the `https` URL from my example.

```
import os
from typing import Optional
import urllib.parse

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QByteArray, QFile, QObject, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkReply, QNetworkRequest


class AsyncDownloader(QObject):
    def __init__(self, url: str, filename: str, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.net_mgr = QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.req = QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url))
        self.fetch_task: Optional[QNetworkReply] = None
        self.data: Optional[QByteArray] = None
        self.file = QFile(filename)

        self.net_mgr.sslErrors.connect(self._ignore_ssl_errors)

    def start_fetch(self):
        self.fetch_task = self.net_mgr.get(self.req)
        self.fetch_task.downloadProgress.connect(self.on_progress)
        self.fetch_task.finished.connect(self.on_finished)
    
    def _ignore_ssl_errors(self, reply: QNetworkReply, errors: List[QSslError]):
        print(f"errors {errors}")
        reply.ignoreSslErrors(errors)
    
    def on_progress(self, bytes_received: int, bytes_total: int):
        print(f"bytes received {bytes_received} (total {bytes_total})")

    def on_finished(self):
        print("finished")
        self.data = self.fetch_task.readAll()
        if not self.file.open(QFile.WriteOnly):
            raise IOError(f"Unable to write to {self.file.fileName}")
        self.file.write(self.data)
        self.file.close()
        print(f"file written to {self.file.fileName()}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pathlib import Path
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

    dl_path = os.path.join(str(Path.home()), "test_dl")
    os.makedirs(dl_path, exist_ok=True)
    app = QApplication([])
    downloader = AsyncDownloader(
        "https://github.com/PiRK/Electrum-ABC-Build-Tools/releases/download/v1.0/tor-linux",
        os.path.join(dl_path, "tor")
    )
    downloader.start_fetch()

    app.exec_()
```

The errors (or warnings?) I'm getting are:

```
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve EVP_PKEY_base_id
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get_peer_certificate
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_get_peer_certificate
errors [<PyQt5.QtNetwork.QSslError object at 0x7fad867112a0>]
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function EVP_PKEY_base_id

bytes received 0 (total 0)
finished
file written to /home/myname/test_dl/tor
```

The file that is written is empty.

I tried adding the following lines just after `self.net_mgr = ....`:

```
    parsed_url = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
    if parsed_url.scheme == "https":
        self.net_mgr.connectToHostEncrypted(parsed_url.hostname)
```

This does not help.

The download work fine with `wget`:

```
$ wget "https://github.com/PiRK/Electrum-ABC-Build-Tools/releases/download/v1.0/tor-linux"
...
tor-linux                                    100%[=============================================================================================>]  15,34M   985KB/s    in 16s

2023-02-16 16:36:51 (969 KB/s) - ‘tor-linux’ saved [16090880/16090880]
```

Comment: Another test I did seems to confirm that it is a `http` vs `https` issue: the URL "http://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/034/467/Communist_Bugs_Bunny_Banner.jpg" works, the same URL with https does not work (empty file at the end, same SSL warnings)

Comment: After doing some research, it seems like QNetworkAccessManager does not work out of the box, it requires some special recompilation of Qt with linking to OpenSSL, which is not a solution for a python program distributed as source code.

Answer (score 0):

After failing to get my `QNetworkAccessManager` to work for HTTPS, I used an alternative solution based on Python's `multiprocessing` standard library and the `requests` library (not stdlib, but recommended by the official python documentation for `urllib.request`).

The only drawback is that I'm not getting any download progress information.

```
import multiprocessing
import requests


class Downloader:
    """URL downloader designed to be run as a separate process and to communicate
    with the main process via a Queue.

    The queue can be monitored for the following messages (as str objects):

      - "@started@"
      - "@HTTP status@ {status code} {reason}"
        (e.g "@HTTP status@ 200 OK")
      - "@content size@ {size in bytes}"
      - "@finished@"
    """

    def __init__(self, url: str, filename: str):
        self.url = url
        self.filename = filename

        self.queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    def run_download(self):
        self.queue.put("@started@")
        r = requests.get(url)
        self.queue.put(f"@HTTP status@ {r.status_code} {r.reason}")
        self.queue.put(f"@content size@ {len(r.content)}")
        with open(self.filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write(r.content)
        self.queue.put("@finished@")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pathlib import Path
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
    import os
    import sys

    url = sys.argv[1]
    fname = sys.argv[2]

    dl_path = os.path.join(str(Path.home()), "test_dl")
    os.makedirs(dl_path, exist_ok=True)
    app = QApplication([])

    downloader = Downloader(
        url,
        os.path.join(dl_path, fname)
    )
    process = multiprocessing.Process(target=downloader.run_download)

    def read_queue():
        while not downloader.queue.empty():
            msg = downloader.queue.get()
            print(msg)

    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(read_queue)
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda: print("."))

    process.start()
    timer.start(500)

    app.exec_()
```

Here is an example of output for a 156 MB file:

```
$ python downloader.py "https://stsci-opo.org/STScI-01GGF8H15VZ09MET9HFBRQX4S3.png" large_img_https.png
@started@
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
@HTTP status@ 200 OK
@content size@ 159725397
@finished@
.
.
.
^Z
[3]+  Stopped                 python downloader.py "https://stsci-opo.org/STScI-01GGF8H15VZ09MET9HFBRQX4S3.png" large_img_https.png
$ kill %3
```